# How to populate credit card input fields with test data in new version of Stripe?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I use [Stripe](https://stripe.com) to create subscriptions and collect payments for my [SaaS application](https://www.billingengine.com/en/).

I've recently switched to Stripe's [Payment Intents API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) and everything seems to be working ok.

Unfortunately, it's no longer possible to design your own input fields for credit card data. All credit card related input fields are now provided directly by Stripe through an iFrame that is embedded into your web page.

In a previous version of Stripe I had a Javascript function on my site in development mode to populate the credit card form fields with test data. However, this is no longer possible since the form fields are now inside the iFrame. I now have to type in the *credit card number*, *expiry data* and *cvc code* manually by hand every time I want to test something.

Is this how it's supposed to be? How can I populate the input fields automatically?

Thanks for any help in this matter.

---

```
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the code that you're using to implement these fields? There are a few different ways to create a payment form using Stripe.js.

Comment: OK, I just added some more code to my initial post. I basically just followed this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart. What's missing is a quick way to populate the form inputs, for testing purposes. The alternative would be to type in `4242 4242 4242 4242, 12/20, 123` manually every time I want to test something.

Comment: You don't need to use elements to create a form. You can mount individual inputs that you create. Instead of mounting card mount each element separately.